# Background Position Property support

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi Im programming a parallax effect on a web site for a client, this site needs to run over IE8+ and all major modern browsers, the problem is that I am using background-position to do the parallax.

IE8 only supports background-positon-y or -x and firefox only support background-position, so I read the documentation on jquery page and they do not recommend to detect browser, instead they recommend to detect property support, so I read the documentation of Modernzr but it seems that there isn't a validation either for background-position (IE9+, and modern browsers) or background-position-x or -y (IE8)

Do you know a good practice or library to detect background-position or background-position-y or -x support?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just set both `background-positon` and `background-positon-x` (and `-y`). The browsers will use the value they support.

Also: as far as I know, IE8 supports `background-position` like almost any major browser. However, you might have some other bugs in your HTML and CSS, which prevents IE8 to use / understand this directive.

Comment: I solved the problem using only background-position, but IE8 always report the error: css(...) is not an objet or is null referencing to the jquery function: css() unless the style is inline, weird, but thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @user3466348 Glad to be able to help. If you are satisfied, you can accept my answer ;)